# Date not getting correctly used for sql in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, rails-activerecord

Please consider following execution and output from rails console

```
root@localhost:/home/gokula/web# rails c production
Loading production environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.1.1 :001 > Customer.sign_up_between( Date.parse("13/11/2014").in_time_zone,  Date.parse("24/11/2014").in_time_zone).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"customers\".* FROM \"customers\"  WHERE (sign_up BETWEEN '2014-11-12 11:00:00.000000' AND '2014-11-23 11:00:00.000000')" 
2.1.1 :002 >  Date.parse("13/11/2014").in_time_zone
 => Thu, 13 Nov 2014 00:00:00 NZDT +13:00 
2.1.1 :003 >
```

When I do to_sql it shows query with 12/11/2014 date but when I execute the date conversion code directly then it works correctly.

Not sure if this is a bug. Please suggest how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord automatically converts every date instance to UTC because it always stores date objects in UTC timezone in the database, to avoid timezone inconsistencies.

If you want to change the default timezone for all your objects, then you can use the configuration `config.active_record.default_timezone`. This setting determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc.

Note that this configuration is global to your entire ActiveRecord usage in the application. To be honest, I would not change it.

Instead, you can passe a time-zone aware object rather than a date, and ActiveRecord will adapt the value. A date has no timezone, but a time object has it.

Use

```
DateTime.parse("2014-11-13 00:00:00 NZDT")
```

instead of

```
Date.parse("13/11/2014")
```

ActiveRecord will appropriately convert the date to the UTC timezone and you'll be able to fetch the correct records.

```
2.1.5 :011 > Date.parse("13/11/2014")
 => Thu, 13 Nov 2014 
2.1.5 :012 > DateTime.parse("2014-11-13 00:00:00 NZDT")
 => Thu, 13 Nov 2014 00:00:00 +1300
```